# How to divide the php array in to multidimensional array? please see below

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the array which looks like below, this data coming from the form which has dynamic fields.

```
Array
(
    [package-name-1] => package1
    [package-serve-1] => sdasd
    [package-price-date-1] => 31-03-2020   
    [foodType-1-1] => Rice
    [foodTags-1-1] => rice
    [foodNotes-1-1] => notes
    [foodchoose-1-1] => 0
    [package-name-2] => package2
    [package-serve-2] => Leaf
    [package-price-date-2] => 12-08-2020
    [foodType-2-2] => rice1
    [foodTags-2-2] => rice1
    [foodNotes-2-2] => dasd
    [foodchoose-2-2] => 3
    [foodType-2-3] => rice2
    [foodTags-2-3] => rice2
    [foodNotes-2-3] => qwewe
    [foodchoose-2-3] => 0
)
```

I want the array output like below, like in two array, array should break from **[package-name]** key and move into separate array.  Output should be like:

```
array(
  [0]=>array(
          [package-name-1] => package1
          [package-serve-1] => sdasd
          [package-price-date-1] => 31-03-2020   
          [foodType-1-1] => Rice
          [foodTags-1-1] => rice
          [foodNotes-1-1] => notes
          [foodchoose-1-1] => 0
       )
   [1]=>array(
          [package-name-2] => package2
          [package-serve-2] => Leaf
          [package-price-date-2] => 12-08-2020
          [foodType-2-2] => rice1
          [foodTags-2-2] => rice1
          [foodNotes-2-2] => dasd
          [foodchoose-2-2] => 3
          [foodType-2-3] => rice2
          [foodTags-2-3] => rice2
          [foodNotes-2-3] => qwewe
          [foodchoose-2-3] => 0
    )
)
```

Comment: It really helps when you make an attempt. That'll quicken the learning process.

Comment: Hint: create a new array, loop, increment and check for key `package-name-$i++`, etc.. As you have it, the array is created in a specific pattern

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi : I tried that earlier and I was stuck at "foodtype" key. I was not sure how to move that as it is dynamic, here is my code: 
```
$i = 1;
  foreach($venue_menu_datails as $venue_menu_info){
   if(isset($venue_menu_datails['package-name-'.$i])){
    $chain_pkgs[$i]['package-name'] = $venue_menu_datails['package-name-'.$i];
    $chain_pkgs[$i]['package-serve'] = $venue_menu_datails['package-serve-'.$i];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through `foreach()` and `strpos()`

```
$newArray = [];

$k = 0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value){

    if(strpos($key,'package-name') !== false){
        $explodedkeys = explode('-',$key);
        $id = end($explodedkeys);
        $k = $id-1;
    }
    $newArray[$k][$key] = $value;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/5eEkA